# Reasons why the ASP.NET Web API Controller cache ignores dynamic assemblies

Tags: asp.net, web-api

I've been reading about how ASP.NET Web API looks up the locations of controllers in assemblies, and ways to dynamically add a new assembly to look in. So far this has all been fine, except I've noticed a few random references to how the controller cache will ignore loading any controller that lives in a dynamic assembly (.IsDynamic == true), and some workarounds to force it to work with a dynamic assembly.

However, I can't find any documentation as to the *why*. Is this just an implementation decision by the ASP.NET team, or is there something more fundamental about this that having a dynamically generated assembly would cause real trouble or breaking something?

Any insights or links to docs that could shed some light on this? I have some guesses, but I'm curious to know the real reasons.

I want to be completely clear that I'm not having trouble making any of this work, I'm wondering why this design route was taken and what caveats accompany it.

Links:

https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/ - specifically references a way to work with dynamic assemblies and that they would be ignored otherwise

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567070/simple-injector-container-fails-to-register-web-api-controller-from-pluggedin-ex - a SO question that lists making sure the assembly is not dynamic in troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Can you provide links to those "random references?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't include the "random links" at first because I assumed ignoring dynamic assemblies was somewhat common knowledge, but not necessarily the reason why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem originates in the .NET Framework itself, not in ASP.NET Web API.

If you look at the code for [DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs) line 80, you'll see that it contains the following comment:

```
// can't call GetExportedTypes on a dynamic assembly
```

Looking up [Assembly.GetExportedTypes() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes(v=vs.110).aspx), it throws `NotSupportedException` with the description "The assembly is a dynamic assembly."

There are several methods in Reflection that don't work on dynamic assemblies, including `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and `Assembly.Load()`.  I suspect this is a security issue; dynamic assemblies cannot be code-signed or afforded any of the usual security protections, and should therefore not be run in full trust, if that's even possible.

**Further Reading**
[Security Issues in Reflection Emit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-issues-in-reflection-emit)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of insight I was hoping for. I was unaware dynamic assemblies had those restrictions, but that makes sense. I'll do some further reading in that area.